# Matrix really slow

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, plugin, performance

Matrix v2.5.5 / EE v2.6.1 / PHP v5.3.3

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="assets" entry_id="16"}
   {test_matrix}    
      {cell_1}
   {/test_matrix}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It takes 17 seconds to load this Matrix of 50 entries. `{cell_1}` is a `File` cell type. If I change that cell type to `Text`, the query runs in under a second, so the issue is something to do with `File` cell type.

Debug

```
(0.042604 / 5.24MB) Calling Class/Method: Channel/entries
(0.042839 / 5.24MB) -> Class Called: Channel
(0.052976 / 5.40MB) -> Method Called: entries
(0.350104 / 8.18MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
(17.881943 / 8.38MB) -> Data Returned
```

Channel field: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTeK.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have enough rep to make a comment. Did you set your file path externally?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not sure I understand. Are you talking about the File Upload Preferences? The path starts with /usr/local/pem/vhosts/

Comment: Is that the entire code in your template?  I'll be doing some reproduction testing here on a similar set of circumstances and will make sure I follow up here as well.

Comment: Yes, that's all that's in the template.

Comment: Hey - so I just did a bit of testing on this and I'm not seeing anything like what you're seeing.  If you create a standalone File Fieldtype - do you see a difference between that and a text input? I'd like to see if this happens without Matrix in play. :)

Comment: Hi Lisa. I added 20 File fields with different files in each. Page loaded in 0.39 Seconds

I then did the same with 20 Text input fields, loaded in .33 seconds.

I then ran a Matrix with 20 files, loaded in 4.8 seconds.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the populated Publish/Edit screen that you're testing Matrix on?

Comment: Hmm, just encountered this exact same problem. I have a matrix with 13 rows, with one file each and it is taking 3 seconds. However, I've never had a problem before with Matrix. Also, you may want to add the tag pixel and tonic or p+t (whichever it is). Not sure if they look at Matrix tag, but adding that may help get P+T's attention.